# Latest Data Available over Time Series Dax Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, powerbi-desktop

I have data with the columns "Date","Care Home", "Accumulative Number of Deaths".

Some care homes will miss submissions for certain dates and these will likely never be filled out.

I would like to chart the data in a time series per day where it sums the most recent available values for each day for each care home. This then needs to be filterable by care home.

Completely stuck with it as every attempt I make comes out with a graph that only sums the submissions on that particular day as below. The graph obviously should not decline at any point.

[Graph Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAhAh.png)

Comment: Could you add some example data in order to help you?

Comment: Also add your current DAX formula, you may want to have a look at the LASTNONBLANK function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone is looking at this it was answered over at reddit and I have created a templated code snippet at https://github.com/SC-TPP/PowerBI-Public/blob/master/Dax%20Measures/Latest%20Known%20Values%20DAX%20Measure.dax

Comment: Please post the relevant portions here, otherwise your answer may get deleted.